# Display the environment variable inside a docker environment

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am setting my Firebase status in the `.env` file with `Firebase=false`. If it is true, some codes will initialize the firebase app. When I try to run the system with `docker-compose up` and run some functions, it will return the error `The default Firebase app does not exist. Make sure to initialize the SDK by calling initialize_app().`

To debug it, I have to check if the firebase variable is really false in my docker environment. I tried to run `docker exec <container> echo "$Firebase"` but it is not displaying anything. Is there any way I can check it?

I also tried `docker exec <container ID>  bash -c 'echo "$Firebase"'` but it also doesn't display anything.

Comment: `docker exec -it <container ID or name> /bin/bash`  You then get a tty and can use your commands

Comment: Can you please post your `docker-compose` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute command inside running container using `docker exec`. More about it [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/).

```sh
docker exec [OPTIONS] CONTAINER COMMAND [ARG...]
```

As an answer to your question, to display environment variables inside docker container execute following:

```sh
docker exec <container ID> env
```